# WebView load HTML but doesn't display

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I have fragments with webview in pager and i have custom htmls to set that webviews. When i paging, some webviews -not every times, sometimes- doesn't show html. When i inspected webviews from `chrome://inspect/` and look the elements webview has, i can see the html but i see blank page in ui. And i'm absolutely sure there is no problem in html. It is very strange.

I set it like this;

```
webViewDetail.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webViewDetail.getSettings().setUserAgentString(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    webViewDetail.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webViewDetail.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webViewDetail.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewDetail.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webViewDetail.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webViewDetail.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webViewDetail.loadDataWithBaseURL("", contentHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

`onReceivedError` doesn't called because there is no problem as i said. Even `onPageFinished`called. But `onPageCommitVisible` doesn't called also.

Comment: **`webViewDetail.loadData(html_value, "text/html", "UTF-8");`**

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Thank you @Prem

Comment: can you share your `contentHtml` with question my friend

Comment: I couldn't. Because it is huge and it exceeds the character limit. But when i tried to share it in snippet, i could see the content in preview. So html is correct, if you ask for this. @Prem

Comment: share snippet i will try to help you

Comment: Man,  it exceeds the character limit. :) Stackoverflow snippet allows 30000 character but it is about 70000 @Prem

Comment: ok fine @AAtaerCaner

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the layout of your webview is correct?

Comment: Yeah. When i inspect it with layout inspector, i can see nothing wrong with layout.